# CakePHP 3 giving wrong pagination output when limit is changed for a custom finder

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

CakePHP 3.7.7

I'm using the Paginator (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html) to display pagination for a query that has 972 rows.

In my Controller method I am loading the Paginator component and using a custom finder called `findFilters()` to return the data that I want paginated.

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
}

public $paginate = [
    'finder' => 'filters', // uses custom finder, findFilters() in src/Model/Table/FiltersTable.php
];

/*
 * Called via ajax. Renders the data and pagination to a template.
 */
public function getFilters()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('ajax');

    $this->loadModel('Filters');

    $rf_keywords = '';
    $rf_keywords = trim($this->request->getData('rf_keywords'));

    // Pagination settings (relevant to the question).           
    $page = $this->request->getData('page') ? (int)$this->request->getData('page') : 1;
    $this->paginate = ['limit' => 200, 'page' => $page];

    $finder = $this
        ->Filters
        ->find('filters' , [
            'rf_keywords' => $rf_keywords
        ]);

    $data = $this
        ->paginate($finder)
        ->toArray(); 

    $this->set('data', $data);
}
```

In my template (`get_filters.ctp`) I have the following to output the pagination numbers (links to be clicked to go between pages) and the total counts:

```
<?= $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>
<?= $this->Paginator->counter([
'format' => 'Page {{page}} of {{pages}}, showing {{current}} records out of
         {{count}} total, starting on record {{start}}, ending on {{end}}'
]) ?>
```

**The problem** is that changing the `limit` in the Controller...

```
$this->paginate = ['limit' => 200];
```

... is not updating the output of the Pagination correctly. See examples below:

`'limit' => 20`:
Shows page numbers 1 - 9 and:

> Page 1 of 49, showing 20 records out of 972 total, starting on record 1, ending on 20

`'limit' => 100`:
Shows page numbers 1 - 9 and:

> Page 1 of 10, showing 100 records out of 972 total, starting on record 1, ending on 100

`'limit' => 500`:
Shows page numbers 1 - 9 and:

> Page 1 of 10, showing 100 records out of 972 total, starting on record 1, ending on 100

`'limit' => 1000` *(more than there are rows in the DB!)*:

Shows page numbers 1 - 9 and:

> Page 1 of 10, showing 100 records out of 972 total, starting on record 1, ending on 100

So there are 2 problems:

1. It doesn't work with any `limit` value >100. Nothing changes in terms of the pagination output in the template. The behaviour is as though it is ignoring anything supplied as the limit and defaulting to 100.
2. The page number links (`$this->Paginator->numbers();`) are always 1 - 9 when the `limit` is >100. That is to say they stay the same irrespective of whether I use a limit of 100, 200, 500, 1000. I'm guessing this is due to problem (1) where it seems to ignore the actual limit set if it's >100.

I thought this was some caching issue. The ajax requests to `getFilters()` are being made via jquery so I have set `cache: false` on them to ensure each request appends a timestamp to the URL to ensure it's not using some old cached response.

I have cleared the files in `tmp/cache/models/*`

I've a force refresh in the browser. Tried an incognito/private browsing window to make sure it's not some session issue.

None of these things solve the problem.

The issue is also consistent if the `page` part of Pagination is altered. For example using `page => 3` will give the correct rows from the database for page 3. But the Pagination HTML will still be exactly the same as where the problem occurs.

Why isn't this working?

Edit - the custom Finder returns the correct data so I don't think this is an issue. The signature is below and it returns a Query object which is executed via Pagination:

```
// src/Model/Table/FiltersTable.php
public function findFilters(Query $query, array $options)
{
     // $query->find() ...
     // ...
     return $query;
}
```

Comment: how looks your finder?

Comment: I've edited the question to show some details

Comment: look at query / debug logs, what is happen when you change limit.

Comment: @Salines I've opened this as a bug on the CakePHP GitHub. The problem is that if you change the `limit` to anything greater than 100 it simply uses 100 as the limit and ignores whatever you've specified. It works fine with values below 100, but not above. Very strange.

Comment: @burzum True, although strangely not the first or last person to have an issue with Cake's documentation... If it was clear then the question might not have been posted.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but the problem is with default `maxLimit` settings for CakePHP 3 pagination, what is set to 100 by default (reference below).

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#limit-the-maximum-number-of-rows-per-page

When you update settings in Controller to, it should do the trick.

```
public $paginate = [
    // Other keys here.
    'maxLimit' => 1000
];
```